# What sql database role must a user have to use a MS Access project file

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Today i tried changing a users role from db owner to db data reader and db data writer. This user uses an Access ADP file, to edit, add and delete records from a few tables in the SQL Server database. However, after doing so he got an OLE error from access on trying to open the ADP. Are there certain security priveleges required by the Access application its self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access has a built-in macro language called Visual Basic for Applications (VBA.)  The OLE error might originate from that.

Try to open the Access application while pressing the SHIFT key.  This should get you into the main Access screen.  Press ALT-F11 to open the Visual Basic editor.  Now, if you open the applications main form, the debugger should pop up if there's an OLE error coming from VBA.  By examining the code that generates the error, it's probably easy to see which permissions are missing.

Comment: when the app opens it creates a record in a table on a seperate database on the same sql server specifying the name of the database being entered, time, the name of the adp file opened and the desk name, would this be affected by changing the permissions of the user to the primary database?

Comment: In SQL Server, a "login" is serverwide, but you have to create a "user" in every database the "login" is allowed to use.  Verify that the "user" exists, and that it has rights to insert the row in that database.